# Android, google cardboard runtime JNI failure

Tags: android, jar, google-cardboard, virtual-reality

I am getting the following error when I integrate Cardboard in my android application. ( I am running it on Samsung S6/Note 3/Nexus 6)

```
... D/CardboardViewNativeImpl﹕ NativeProxy not found
... D/CardboardViewNativeImpl﹕ Loading native library vrtoolkit
... D/CardboardViewNativeImpl﹕ Native library loaded
... W/art﹕ Attempt to remove local handle scope entry from IRT, ignoring
... W/art﹕ Attempt to remove local handle scope entry from IRT, ignoring
... W/art﹕ Attempt to remove local handle scope entry from IRT, ignoring
... A/art﹕ art/runtime/check_jni.cc:65] JNI DETECTED ERROR IN APPLICATION: GetMethodID received null jclass
... A/art﹕ art/runtime/check_jni.cc:65]     in call to GetMethodID
... A/art﹕ art/runtime/check_jni.cc:65]     from long com.google.vrtoolkit.cardboard.CardboardViewNativeImpl.nativeInit(int, int, float, float, float, long)
... A/art﹕ art/runtime/check_jni.cc:65] "main" prio=5 tid=1 Runnable
... A/art﹕ art/runtime/check_jni.cc:65]   | group="main" sCount=0 dsCount=0 obj=0x73617000 self=0xb4827800
... A/art﹕ art/runtime/check_jni.cc:65]   | sysTid=24304 nice=0 cgrp=default sched=0/0 handle=0xb6f04bec
... A/art﹕ art/runtime/check_jni.cc:65]   | state=R schedstat=( 1668176075 289166273 1700 ) utm=148 stm=18 core=1 HZ=100
... A/art﹕ art/runtime/check_jni.cc:65]   | stack=0xbe04a000-0xbe04c000 stackSize=8MB
... A/art﹕ art/runtime/check_jni.cc:65]   | held mutexes= "mutator lock"(shared held)
```

I have also the added abiFilters, since cardbaord.jar file has the .so file only for armeabi-v7a. But still getting the error.

```
buildTypes {
debug {
    ...
        ndk {
            abiFilters "armeabi-v7a" // includes ARM SO files only, so no x86 SO file
        }
    }
```

I was able to create a standalone cardbaord application and run it on all three devices without issue, only when I integrate with the existing app its failing at runtime.

Answer (score 2):

I have this exact same problem that it works when it's standalone, but breaks with "GetMethodID received null jclass" when I integrate it to an existing app.

It turns out I have ProGuard enabled in the integrated app, adding the following rule fixed it:

```
-keep class com.google.vrtoolkit.cardboard.** { *; }
```

Comment: This should be the accepted answer, it fixed my issue as well.

Answer (score 0):

For new Cardboard SDK 0.8.0 I had to add the following ProGuard rules:

```
-keep class com.google.vr.**
-keepclassmembers class com.google.vr.** { *; }
-keep class com.google.vr.**$*
-keepclassmembers class com.google.vr.**$* { *; }
-keep class com.google.geo.render.**
-keepclassmembers class com.google.geo.render.** { *; }

# Also keept this rule, just in case (probably only needed for 0.7.0)
-keep class com.google.vrtoolkit.cardboard.** { *; }
```

I was a bit in a hurry, and because of that maybe I've been too "conservative" on the rules. I've checked it on both *panowidget* (still image) and *videowidget* (video) examples and it works in both cases.